Calculating the maximal value of a positive quadratic form
$\newcommand{\tr}{\mathrm{tr}}$Suppose $P, Q$ are two real, symmetric positive definite matrices and $v$ a nonzero unit vector.
Consider
$$
f(X) = v^T(P + X^{-1})^{-1} v + v^T(Q + X^{-1})^{-1} v.
$$
Question: What is the value of$$
F^\star = \sup\{ f(X) : X \succ 0, \tr(X) \leq 1\}?
$$

In the case $P = Q$:
Since $X \preceq I$, clearly $f(X) \leq 2 v^T (P + 
I)^{-1} v$. Approximating $xx^T$ by positive definite matrices gives
$$F^\star \geq 2\, \sup_{x : \|x\|_2 = 1}  \frac{(v^T x)^2}{x^T(P+I)x} = 2 v^T (P + I)^{-1} v,$$ by Cauchy-Schwarz.
Thus, if $P = Q$,$$
F^\star = 2 v^T (P + I)^{-1} v.
$$
I am unsure how to proceed to $P \neq Q$.

I'd be curious to know what you mean by "approximating $xx^T$ by positive definite matrices". Are you taking a limit as $X$ approaches $xx^T$? If so, then how did you evaluate that limit?

I suspect it would be helpful to rewrite
$$
(P + X^{-1})^{-1} = \
(X^{-1/2}(X^{1/2}PX^{1/2} + I)X^{-1/2})^{-1} = \
X^{1/2}(X^{1/2}PX^{1/2} + I)^{-1}X^{1/2}
$$
All together, you could write
$$
f(X) = v^TX^{1/2}[(X^{1/2}PX^{1/2} + I)^{-1} + (X^{1/2}QX^{1/2} + I)^{-1}]X^{1/2}v.
$$

I evaluate that limit precisely as you indicated above. The function can be written without explicitly writing down the inverse of $X$.

That makes sense in retrospect

Can we prove (or disprove by counterexample) that the optimal $X$ has rank one?

Hm @RiverLi I doubt this is true. Let me see if I can find an example.

Hm, tricky I had a hard time finding a counter example?

@River Li, For the case of $P=Q$, I think we can prove the objective function is strongly convex. Hence the optimal solution is unique and rank-1

@goldboy Yes, $P = Q$, there is closed form solution?

@River Li, the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_{\max}((P+I)^{-1}vv^{\top})$

@goldboy OP has given that. When $P\ne Q$, I think it is not necessarily rank one.

Some thoughts.
Note that
$$(P + X^{-1})^{-1} = P^{-1} PX(PX + I)^{-1} = P^{-1} - (PXP + P)^{-1}.$$
Thus, we equivalently solve the following convex optimization problem:
\begin{align*}
 &\min_{X} \quad v^\top (PXP + P)^{-1}v + v^\top(QXQ + Q)^{-1}v\\
 &\mathrm{subject\ to}\quad X\succeq 0, \quad \mathrm{tr}(X) \le 1.
\end{align*}
It can be written as
\begin{align*}
 &\min_{X, \, y,\, z} \quad y + z\\
 &\mathrm{subject \ to}\quad X \succeq 0, \quad \mathrm{tr}(X) \le 1, \\
 &\qquad\qquad\quad \begin{pmatrix}
  y & v^\top \\
  v & PXP + P
 \end{pmatrix} \succeq 0, \\
&\qquad\qquad\quad \begin{pmatrix}
 z & v^\top \\
 v & QXQ + Q
\end{pmatrix} \succeq 0. 
\end{align*}
We did some numerical experiments via CVX+matlab. Often it outputs $X$ which is not rank one.

Are you able to at least prove that for some choice of $P, Q$ that the optimal solution is not rank-one (i.e., rank-one is strictly worse than larger rank)?

@DrewBrady You can try the example: $v = [-1; 4], P = [21\ -28; -28\ 42], Q = [27 \ 23;23\ 30]$.

Proving this by hand is very difficult, though.

@DrewBrady But why do it by hand? You can use Maple etc. to simplify the expressions.
